# Override ansible default ssh_user

Tags: ssh, configuration, ansible

99% of the time that I use ansible, I use the ansible_ssh_user specified in my hosts file. The other 1% of the time this user doesn't exist, and I need to use the default user to create it. How can I run a playbook in such a way that it overrides the ansible_ssh_user in the hosts file?

I tried the following:

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yaml --user default --ask-pass
```

But this still produced the following error:

```
fatal: [target]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Permission denied, please try again.", "unreachable": true}
```

It only worked after I commented out the ansible_ssh_user in my hosts file, but it would be pretty inconvenient to comment/uncomment this line every time.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass extra variables on the ansible-playbook command line to redefine the Ansible user. For example:

```
ansible-playbook .... --extra-vars "ansible_ssh_user=nobody"
```

The man page says:

```
       -e, --extra-vars
          set  additional  variables  as  key=value  or YAML/JSON, if filename
          prepend with @
```

So you can pass key/value pairs, YAML, JSON, or a file containing variables to use. But the single key-value pair is probably enough for your case.

---

This is a good time to review your provisioning process. I make sure the ansible user is created with the proper ssh authorized_keys in all my kickstarts, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case I'm working with Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 3s, so there isn't a lot of wiggle room in the provisioning process to create new users - hence I need to use "pi" the first time and my own user after that.

Comment: Roll your own SD card image, then.

Comment: The thing about rollling my own image is it implies an entirely new area to ansibilize as I have to make these changes to every image released in the future. I think that's a bit beyond the scope of this project but I'll consider it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Michael's answer which is correct, you can specify `ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER` in the environment, set `remote_user` in your ansible.cfg, and/or set `remote_user` at the top of your playbook.